# Kibana visualize - show most recent without aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, kibana, dashboard, kibana-4

My setup is to have Spark do my data processing, and Kibana as my dashboard. Spark is doing some complicated computation, and I just want Kibana to display the most recent result.

I assume this is a common use case, and having Spark do my processing and Kibana as my frontend should be a reasonable setup. If not, please advise.

In Kibana visualize/dashboard, there are various aggregation methods, like "Count", "Average", "Sum", "Min", "Max"...etc.

Is there a way to show "Most recent" in Kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3286) for max(@timestamp) shows as fixed (but I don't see if it's been released).

[This one](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/678) for latest shows as coming in Kibana 4.5

Hope that helps.